# K&R c book a stripped-down version of Unix sort

Tags: c, pointers

When I do this examples on section 5.6, which is a sort program to sort a set of textlines into alphabetic order: I just write the code and start to run it, and I found something not quite right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "alloc.c"
#define MAXLENGH 100 /* max length per line  */
#define MAXLINES 100 /* max lines to be sorted  */
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];/* pointers to the text lines  */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void strcopy(char *s, char *t);
void qsort(char *linestr[], int left, int right);
int stringcmp(char *, char *);
/* sort input lines  */
int main(){
   int nlines; /* the number of input lines read  */
   if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) > 0){
       qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines -1);
       writelines(lineptr, nlines);
       return 0;
   }else{
       return 1;
   }
}
int my_getline(char *, int);
/* read input lines  */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines){
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLENGH];
    nlines = 0;
    while((len = my_getline(line, MAXLENGH)) > 0){
        //if (nlines >= MAXLENGH || (p = alloc(len)) == NULL)
          //  return -1;
        //else {
            line[len -1] = '\0';
            strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
    }
    return nlines;
}

void writelines(char *lineptr[], int lines){
    while(lines-- > 0)
        printf("%s\n", *lineptr++);
}
int my_getline(char *s, int limit){
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < limit -1 && (c = getchar())!= '\n' && c != EOF;i++)
         *s++ = c;
    if (c == '\n'){
         *s++ = '\n';
         i++;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    return i;
}
/* qsort:sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order  */
void swap(char *v[],int i, int j);
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right){
    int i, last;
    if (left >= right)/* do nothing if the array contains less than 2 elements*/
       return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++){
        if (stringcmp(v[i], v[left]) > 0){
            swap(v, ++last, i);
        }
    }
    swap(v, last, left);
    qsort(v, left, last -1);
    qsort(v, last + 1, right);
}
* qsort:sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order  */
void swap(char *v[],int i, int j);
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right){
    int i, last;
    if (left >= right)/* do nothing if the array contains less than 2 elements*/
       return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++){
        if (stringcmp(v[i], v[left]) > 0){
            swap(v, ++last, i);
        }
    }
    swap(v, last, left);
    qsort(v, left, last -1);
    qsort(v, last + 1, right);
}
int stringcmp(char *s, char *t){
    while (*s++ == *t++)
            ;
    if (*t == '\0')
       return 0;
    else
       return 1;
}
void swap(char *v[], int i, int j){
    char *temp;
    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
void strcopy(char *s, char *t){
    while(*s++ = *t++)
            ;
}
```

For most of part, there is no need to worry about, but for this line:

```
line[len -1] = '\0';
strcpy(p, line);
lineptr[nlines++] = p;
```

when it comes to strcpy, which is to copy a string, it will cause segmentation fault;

```
A string can be initialized in different ways
Segmentation fault
```

then I write another program to verify my thought:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
   char *p;
   char line[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
   strcpy(p, line);
   return 0;
}
```

It will give me same error, I assume the code in this book is correct, but It does run into crash, (by the way I only currently care about the segmentation error part, for other parts, ignore them please) am I missing some code part? any advice is thankful!

Comment: Keep in mind K&R C is an anachronism at this point as the C standard has moved on.

Comment: `p` is uninitialized, so it's undefined behaviour. This could result in a crash.

Comment: you are right, for that part, I guess it is anachronism, so I would change, thx for explaining...

Comment: You can't copy data into a pointer that doesn't point anywhere.  p should point to the result of alloc.  And in fact the code does `p = alloc(len)` but you have commented it out.

Comment: @tadman Sloppily written, needlessly complex code such as the one found in K&R was never the proper way to write C though. Not even in the 1970s. There is a certain kind of unreadable mess one often encounters here on SO, where you can tell that the OP has been damaged by K&R. Like Brian Kernighan said: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are by definition not smart enough to debug it." A shame he didn't practice what he preached, because almost every code example in the book is a mess.

Comment: @Lundin Honestly the K&R C book, despite being the "de-facto" reference, is so full of WTF moments that it's more of an art piece than documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is uninitialized, so it's undefined behaviour. This could result in a crash. You're writing to junk memory when you `strcpy()` to it.

The fix is to base this off of `line` when you copy, and use `malloc()`:

```c
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines){
    int len;
    int nlines = 0; // Try and keep your declarations and initializations together
    char line[MAXLENGH]; // LENGH??

    while((len = my_getline(line, MAXLENGH)) > 0){
      line[len -1] = '\0';
      char *p = malloc(strlen(line) + 1); // Allocate memory
      strcpy(p, line); // Now this is valid

      lineptr[nlines++] = p; // Also works
    }

    return nlines;
}
```

If you have access to POSIX `strdup()` then use that instead:

```c
lineptr[nlines++] = strdup(line); // Easy!
```